# How to get the controller address/ID

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using [confluent Kafka Go](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) for my project. When writing tests, because of the asynchronous nature of Kafka when creating a topic, I might be have errors (error code 3: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION) when create the topic then get back immediately.

As I understood, if I can query directly on the controller, I can always get the lastest meta data. So my question is: How can I get Kafka controller's IP or ID when using Confluent Kafka Go.

Comment: Typically your tests would create the topic programmatically. Otherwise you end up with the default number of partitions, replicas, and other topic settings

Comment: I agree that my tests will create the topic programmatically. However, you don't know the next operator will be successfully or not. (e.g: insert a message into that topic because that topic might not exist)

Comment: Right. Though, this code that creates them looks blocking to me. https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/admin_create_topic/admin_create_topic.go#L87

Comment: The result is only on the node that the client connected to.

Comment: AdminAPI has a method named `GetMetadata` that is hard  to understand with me. I don't know what is the difference when  `allTopics` flag is set to true and topic is not null.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/adminapi.go#L858
As the comment here, it looks like `allTopics` does not matter when the topic is not null. But I run example with defined topic + allTopics = true and defined topic + allTopics = false, they yield the different result.